# ZPL - Code 128 Understanding better how to use Subsets B and C

Tags: zpl, code128

I'm getting involved with ZPL (a little bit) since a few days, so I'm sorry if the questions will look stupid.
I've got to build a bar code 128 and I finally realized: I got to make it as shorter as possible.
My main question is: is it possible to switch to subset C and then back to B for just 2 digits? I read the documentation and subset C will ready digits from 00 to 99, so in theory it should work, practically, will it be worth it?
Basically when I translate a bar code with Zebra designer, and print it to a file, it doesn't bother to switch to subset C for just a couple of digits.
This is the text I need to see in the bar code:
AB1C234D567890123456

By the documentation I read, I would build something like this:

```
FD>:AB1C>523>64D>5567890123456
```

Instead Zebra Designer does:

```
FD>:AB1C234D>5567890123456
```

So the other question is, will the bar code be the same length? Actually, will mine be shorter? [I don't have a printer with me at the moment]
Last question:
Let's say I don't want to spend much time scripting this up, will the following work ok, or will it make the bar code larger?

```
AB1C>523>64D>556>578>590>512>534>556
```

So I can just build a very simple script which checks two chars per time, if they're both numbers, then add >5 to the string.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, some nice loose terminology. Do you mean couple="exactly 2" or couple="a few"?

Changing from one subset to another takes one code element, so for exactly 2 digits, you'd need one element to change and one to represent the 2 digits in subset C. On the other hand, staying with your original subset would take 2 elements - so no, it's not worth the change.

Further, if you were to change to `C` for 2 digits and then back to your original, the change would actually be costly - `C`(12)`B` = 3 elements whereas 12 would only be 2.

If you repeat the exercise for 4 digits, then switching to `C` would generate `C`(12)(34) = 3 elements against 4 to stay with what you have; or `C`(12)(34)`B` = 4 elements if you switch and change back, or 4 elements if you stick - so no gain.

With 6 or more successive numerics, then you gain regardless of whether or not you switch back.

So overall,
2-digit terminal : No difference
2-digit other : code is longer
4-digit terminal : code is shorter
4-digit other : no difference
more than 4 digits : code is shorter.

And an ODD number of digits would need to be output in code A or B for the first digit and then the above table applies to the remainder.

Comment: Yup, sorry, I meant exactly two. Anyway THANKS! I don't have enough reputation to mark it as an answer, but this answer was great and gave me all the info I needed. I now understand that switching to a different subset will add an extra element and made things way more clear. On the template I'm working on, the last 12 chars are always numbers, so, for now, I'll leave the template as it is:
starting with B, the switching to C for the last 12 digits. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but specifying `A` (Automatic Mode) as the final parameter to the `^BC` command will make the printer do this for you.

Example:

```
^XA
^FO100,100
^BY3
^BCN,100,N,N,A
^FD0123456789^FS
^XZ
```